# Faced problem while applying OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, classification, data-mining, categorical-data, encoding

For classification, I was trying to convert categorical data into numeric by applying OneHotEncoder. But it shows error `could not convert string to float`

Here is the sample of my categorical data set and code of One Hot Encoding.

[image]

`# TODO: create a OneHotEncoder object, and fit it to all of X
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder`

`# 1. INSTANTIATE
enc = OneHotEncoder()`

`# 2. FIT
enc.fit(train_obj)`

`# 3. Transform
train_ = enc.transform(train_obj)
train_.head()`

And error message:
[image]

I couldn't understand what's the problem & how could I solve it.

If I apply `get_dummies()` method, is it similar of OneHotEncoder ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following demo:

Source DF:

```
In [53]: df
Out[53]:
   A          B                   C
0  1  Bachelors  Married-civ-spouse
1  2    HS-grad            Divorsed
2  3       11th  Married-civ-spouse
```

**Option 1:**

```
In [54]: for c in df.columns[df.dtypes.eq('object')]:
    ...:     df = df.join(df[c].str.get_dummies())
    ...:
```

Result:

```
In [55]: df
Out[55]:
   A          B                   C  11th  Bachelors  HS-grad  Divorsed  Married-civ-spouse
0  1  Bachelors  Married-civ-spouse     0          1        0         0                   1
1  2    HS-grad            Divorsed     0          0        1         1                   0
2  3       11th  Married-civ-spouse     1          0        0         0                   1
```

**Option 2:**

```
In [58]: df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.select_dtypes(['object'])))

In [59]: df
Out[59]:
   A          B                   C  B_11th  B_Bachelors  B_HS-grad  C_Divorsed  C_Married-civ-spouse
0  1  Bachelors  Married-civ-spouse       0            1          0           0                     1
1  2    HS-grad            Divorsed       0            0          1           1                     0
2  3       11th  Married-civ-spouse       1            0          0           0                     1
```

Answer (score 0):

To get from a `string` to **one hot encoding** is basically a 2-step process.

`sklearn`'s `OneHotEncoder` function:

> Encode[s] categorical **integer** features using a one-hot aka one-of-K
>   scheme. (see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html))

So, one first has to convert `strings` to `integers`, which can be easily done using `sklearn`'s `LabelEncoder`:

> Encode labels with value between 0 and n_classes-1. (see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html))

There several such examples on `StackOverflow`, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588679/issue-with-onehotencoder-for-categorical-features).